# simple question about the degree of a divisor on riemann surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $C=H \cap S$  where $S$ is a surface of general type canonically embedded in $\mathbb{P}^N$ for some $N>0$ and $H$ the divisor of an hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^N$. $H_{|C}$ is a divisor on $C$.
What is the degree of it?

Answer (score 3):

The degree is $(H\cdot H)$, the self-intersection number.